# Issues handling strings with .encode('string-escape') method

Tags: python, string, encode

I am working with variables containing directory paths in python on a windows machine, and as such need to convert string litterals to raw strings (removing escape sequences). All is fine when i use the os.getcwd() function and convert using the method .encode('string-escape'), but as soon as i try doing the same with a hard coded string it wont work. This is especially confusing as both objects are of the same type (string), and as such should behave in exactly the same way.
My code is:

```
import os
dir1 = os.getcwd()
type1 = type(dir1)
print type1
print dir1.encode('string-escape')
print "\n\n"
dir2 = "C:\Users\StaM\Desktop\brba\test1"
type2 = type(dir2)
print type2
print dir2.encode('string-escape')
```

And my output is:

```
<type 'str'>
C:\\Users\\StaM\\Desktop\\brba\\test1


<type 'str'>
C:\\Users\\StaM\\Desktop\x08rba\test1
```

As you can see both objects are the same type yet the behaviour is different in handling escape sequences. Any ideas on why this is happening and how to get this to work properly? All explanations / suggestions / solutions would be highly appreciated, I really want to understand what is going on here. Thnx

Please note: This question is about the .encode() method and not 'r' flag... Using the 'r' flag for raw strings is not an option here, as i am passing the variables containing directory paths into my program to construct a larger string to represent DOS commands.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Unfortunately raw strings are not an option here, as i am passing the variables containing the directory paths into my program to construct a larger string which will be used as a DOS command, in the form os.popen.(cmd).

Comment: The non-raw string literals are producing what is effectively "corrupt" data. If your strings are not corrupt, they won't produce this result. If you have string literals, you should be able to prepend `r`. If you have string data, no action should be necessary. If you only have the corrupt strings... it might be possible to produce a reverse mapping of Python string literal escape sequences to infer the original string, but that is a hacky last resort. I'm not sure I entirely understand how you're getting these -- is your Python file being generated?

Comment: @JeremyBanks I'am sorry i don't understand where you get this ..."corrupt" strings concept. Raw strings do not behave appropriately when passed into variables and reused to construct a second larger string. Which justifies the use of the .encode() method.  And no the Python file is not generated...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that the os.getcwd() function returns a pre-formatted string inclusive of double "\" even when pre-fixed to an escape character. While the .encode() method will only append the second "\" if the character that follows it is not an escape character.

```
>>> import os
>>> dir = os.getcwd()
>>> print "%r" %dir
'C:\\Users\\StaM\\Desktop\\brba\\test1'
```

The solution here is to use a dictionary to define all possible escape characters, then use a loop to locate these characters in the string in question and to append a secondary "\" directly preceding any escape characters. This should be done prior to using the .encode() method. 
BOOM!

Comment: The string from `os.getcwd()` doesn't contain double-slashes, it just needs to be encoded as double-slashes in a non-raw string literal, which you're producing with `%r`. If you used `print` you'd see the real string, without the double-backslash.